# Compare a string with other row and delete the string and display the left over data

Tags: excel

Column A :Rouviere
Column B :Chateau Routas Coteaux Varois Rouviere

I should result in column C as : Chateau Routas Coteaux Varois

Can anyone help me with the formula in excel.

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,""))
```

[image]